# HighCharts isn't working

Tags: php, html, css, charts, highcharts

I just created a `php` page with `highcharts`. I followed the instructions on their site and ended up not working the charts. I don't know what is the reason why my chart isn't working. also about the Jq.js that is the jquery.js, I just renamed it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="jschart/jq.js"></script>
<script src="jschart/jschart.js"></script>

<script src="jschart/esporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () { 
    $('container')({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body background="http://www.footpatrol.co.uk/templates/footpatrol.co.uk/_images//blog/_2013/adidas-Rick-Owens-Tech-Runner/adidas-Rick-Owens-Tech-Runner-10.jpg" >

<div id ="content">

 <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;">asdf</div>

 <div style="width:100%" >
  <table class="tablename" border="2" style="margin: auto">
  <tr  style="font-size:30px">
   <th>NCFS</th>
   <th>NFCL</th>
   <th>MICROTOP</th>
   <th>SONION</th>
   <th>ZAMA</th>
   <th>TOYOTA</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>asdfasdf</td>
   <td>asdfasdf</td>
   <td>asdfasdf</td>
   <td>asdfasdf</td>
   <td>asdfasdf</td>
   <td>asdfasdf</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </div>


</div>
 
 
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: you are missing a hash, should be `$('#container')({`...

Comment: ohhh ill checked it

Comment: still not working @Azola

Comment: @EarvinNillCastillo the initialising function should be in a `document.ready` function

Comment: how to put it there?

Comment: @Azola iputted the document.ready but still aint working

Comment: Did you include JQuery? @EarvinNillCastillo

Answer (score 1):

1. I am not sure is `jq.js` is jquery library or not. If not then include `jquery library`
2. `$('container')` should be `$('#container')`

Comment: where to add new jquery.js

Comment: if jq.js is not jquery library then add it before jq.js included

Comment: @EarvinNillCastillo thanks for the demo. In JS file you can not add script tag. Anyway can you please give me url of js files (e.g: jq.js, jschart.js and son) you included so that I can setup codepen demo?

Comment: its just present here in my computer.

Comment: If you didn't fix it yet, please provide your those JS code